# Openlayers 6: Simplifying a Feature<LineString> with properties

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, openlayers-6

**Background**

I use Openlayer 6 where I have a `Feature<LineString>` which I want to simplify.

The solution display multiple `Feature<LineString>` which each has a property named `velocities`. The list of velocities corresponds 1-to-1 to the coordinates of the feature.

**Question**

Is there a way to simplify the `Feature<LineString>` via e.g. `simplify()` using the *Douglas Peucker algorithm* which simplifies both the coordinates and the corresponding properties e.g. `velocities`?

Comment: OpenLayers uses a 2 dimensional simplification, so XYZ or XYM coordinates are reduced to XY, but there are third party 3 dimensional JavaScript implementations available, for example https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js/tree/3d where you could set the velocities as the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js/tree/3d where you can simplify a 3d point x,y = point, and z is velocity.